# How to wrap div within absolute position elements

Tags: html, css

Codepen: http://codepen.io/eguneys/pen/jPRexo

I have a parent with `position:relative` and two child with `position:absolute` side by side:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child child1'>
  </div>
  <div class='child child2'>
  </div>
</div>

.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90px;
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child1 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.child2 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 70px;
}
```

I want to put the children in a group:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child-group'>
    <div class='child child1'/>
    <div class='child child2'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

So that `child-group` wraps two children. (The `child-group` border is around two `child`).

This should work for wherever the children are absolutely positioned. They will be always side by side and `child-group` should wrap them.

### Notes

In case this is not possible, what is a possible solution to have borders around the children?

I can set the width of the `child-group` with js so that I can calculate.

http://codepen.io/eguneys/pen/jPRexo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't position the `child` divs, position the `child-group` wrapper.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.child-group {
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.child {
  float: left;
  height: 90px;
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child-group'>
    <div class='child child1'>
    </div>
    <div class='child child2'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```